# C++ abstract class problem

Tags: c++, c++11, abstract-class

I have an abstract class defined as follows:

```
class AnimatedDraw
{
public:
    virtual void Draw(sf::RenderWindow &window) = 0;
    virtual void Draw(sf::RenderWindow &window, sf::Shader shader) = 0;
    virtual void Update(sf::Clock &time) = 0;
};
```

I'm trying to inherit from it into another class defined as follows:

```
class ScreenLayer explicit : public AnimatedDraw
{
public:
    ScreenLayer(void);
    virtual void Draw(sf::RenderWindow &window) override; //I'll need to be able to override these again in subclasses
    virtual void Draw(sf::RenderWindow &window, sf::Shader &shader) override;
    virtual void Update(sf::Clock &clock) override;
    ~ScreenLayer(void);
};
```

The source file is empty functions right now and is as follows:

```
#include "ScreenLayer.h"
ScreenLayer::ScreenLayer(void)
{
}
void ScreenLayer::Draw(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
}
void ScreenLayer::Draw(sf::RenderWindow &window, sf::Shader &shader)
{
}
void ScreenLayer::Update(sf::Clock &clock)
{
}
ScreenLayer::~ScreenLayer(void)
{
}
```

I'm doing something wrong, as my compiler (VC2010) produces several errors, including complaining it can't find `ScreenLayer` in the `ScreenLayer.cpp` file, and several about this line `class ScreenLayer explicit : public AnimatedDraw` I haven't tried to use explicit overrides before, but according to the [C++0x article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Explicit_virtual_function_overrides), that is how you do it. Does VC2010 not support explicit overrides, or did i mess something else up?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I was under the impression that this use of explicit and override was not accepted into C++0x in favor of attributes.  Are you sure that this will be legal under the new standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it doesn't support `explicit`. It's fine because it [probably won't go to the standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3234.pdf).